# How To Add Instagram oAuth To My Website

Tags: wordpress, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

So I am working on a website that revolves around Instagram. With this being said I am trying to allow people to sign in to their Instagram account on the website so that they can follow the Instagram pages that are featured on the website. I have looked for wordpress plugins but those only allow you to comment on objects on the website. I have done alot of research on Instagram oAuth but it has me very confused since I am not an expert. If someone could help me that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://instagram.com/developer/ -> Manage Clients -> Add Client

Fill up the description and redirect url it should your oauth page..

PHP

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?scope=likes&client_id=".CLIENT_ID."&redirect_uri=".REDIRECT."&response_type=code"
```

For access token

```
if($_REQUEST['action']=="oauth")
```

{

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=".CLIENT_ID."&client_secret=".CLIENT_SECRET."&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=".urlencode(REDIRECT)."&code=".$_REQUEST['code']);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

exit();
```

}

Comment: Thanks man for the reply but I have already added a client but i guess i am a bit confused on what you mean by redirect it to my oauth page. Could you further explain. I guess i dont know as much as i though i did.